# Variables are getting shuffled in .sh

Tags: shell

I am using a config file and awk command to read the config values in the shell script. I am getting the correct value from the config file when I am echoing it.

But when I am concatenating it url it is getting shuffled.

My code is below

test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
CONFIG=app.conf
link=$(awk '/^URL/{print $3}' "${CONFIG}")
echo "link: $link"
echo "full url: $link/auth/tokens"
```

app.conf

```
URL = https://localhost/test
```

It prints
link: https://localhost/test
full url: /auth/tokenshost/test

where it has to print
full url: https://localhost/test/auth/tokens

What might be wrong in the script?

Answer (score 0):

Your config file ends with a '\r', like from a windows/dos file.
Try something like
`link=$(awk '/^URL/{print $3}' "${CONFIG}"| tr -d '\r')`

Comment: Thanks Walter.. It is working. Can you please explain me what tr -d '\r' does?

Comment: Your lines in the config file are ending with `\r\n`. There are different ways to remove the `\r` character. I don't like `dos2unix`, what might behave different on other *nix systems. The `tr` can replace or delete characters. It is a simple tool and with the -d characters are removed.
Maybe better to convert inside `awk` and not calling another tool with `{sub("\r", ""); print $3}`

Comment: Hi Walter, got it thanks for you time and explanation.